# What is the latency for awarding badges?

Tags: support, badges

I was taking a look over my old answers, and it appears [for this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36199/9043) I qualify for the [Populist badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist), i.e. my answer has more than twice the upvotes of the accepted answer, and the accepted answer is at least 10 points, and has been for a while I guess. Does anyone know what the latency in awarding badges is? Does it vary from badge to badge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latency depends on the badge. There are scripts which check if the condition for the badge(s) are met and award them. Sometimes the rules of a badge are actually slightly different than it is described and then there might be some internal time limit, i.e. you might need more that twice up-votes then the accepted one for a certain time in order to make sure it isn't just a glitch.

Comment: Oh, weirdly the badge just got awarded. Did you poke a script?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: No, moderators don't have access to them. Only some SX employees can do something about it. It was just a coincident I guess.

Comment: One of those things! Thanks for the answer in any case. I'm thinking that each badge is governed by its own script executed by a cron job. Do you know if this is correct, or is this privileged knowledge of the SX employees?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt and @ MartinScharrer: See the [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for a detailed reference on the badge requirements. Specifically for the [Populist badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist), the abbreviated description is not very clear. Translated, "more than 10" -> "at least 11"; "more than 2x" -> "at least 23 and more than twice the accepted answer score". 23 is "more than 2x" 11.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the pointer. I didn't realise there were fuller descriptions available. The one I was looking at was as clear as mud!

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Hence my recent question: [Add a reference to the ultimate badge description list](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1990/5764)

Answer (score 10):

Some random observations:

- Many badges are awarded a few seconds after the awarding condition has been met. This is true for most "common" badges like "Nice Question" and "Nice Answer", but possibly also for the rare "Epic" and "Legendary" Badges.
- Some badges, e.g. "Enlightened", will be awarded in blocks about once every hour.
- Tag badges will be awarded once every 24 hours, about 3 a.m. UTC.

Comment: Indeed, I usually get "Enlightened" about one hour after getting "Nice Answer", after an accepted, first answer of mine went to +10.

Comment: Either the tag badge description is off, or the delay is much longer, or Christmas is slowing down servers somewhere, but I've been hanging for at least two days the for silver `mathmode` tag badge.

Comment: @Werner As of yesterday, you had [a score of 416 from 79 non-wiki answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathmode/topusers) in `mathmode`. You need a score of 400 from at least 80 non-wiki answers, so you were one answer short.

Comment: @Werner Note that while your tag page shows "80" for `mathmode`, this is for one question and 79 answers.